# pfsense subdomain timeout with error 522

Tags: letsencrypt, cloudflare, pfsense

I want to attach a valid ssl subdomain to my pfsense. I would check it (with warnings) via my the pfsense's IP 192.168.11.1 .

I used multiple tutorials to come up with the following:

1. Bought a domain
2. Set the domain's namespace to cloudflair
3. Setup an cloud flair API key with dns zone edit rights and collected various cloudflair details.
4. Created an A record with a subdomain pointing to my static external ip

In my pfsense, I

1. Installed ACME
2. Added two ACME keys (one for staging and another for production)
3. Created a certificate successfully (both in staging and production)
4. Set my pfsense to new certificate
5. Added my subdomain to the additional hostnames

At this point of time it worked. I thought I had more to do since I didn't know how the browser was resolving to my pfsense's IP.

The next day, it stopped working with the Error 522. Its complaining with a Cloudflair view that states my Host is the problem. I can still access the pfsense via IP.

Did I miss anything? What reason did it stop working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an A record on my local DNS server and pointed it to my IP. Bam, it worked again!